# How to get the path of the final final point by a symbolic link using `stat`

Tags: c, ls

I try to get the name of the folder / file pointed by the symbolic link.

For example, when you do `ls -l`
You can get this result

```
-rw-r--r--  1 macos  staff  0 Feb 22 12:05 test
lrwxr-xr-x  1 macos  staff  7 Feb 19 11:05 sl -> test
```

How could I do, if I know the path of sl to get the file/folder here it pointed to ?

I want to do it using `stat` if possible.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: *Why* would you use `lstat` when it's obviously not the right function to use? Why not use `stat` which *will* follow the link?

Comment: Well actually it's because I got confused !
I though that `lstat` follow the link and `stat` not !

Comment: In any case, to get the path you'd use readlink, it's not returned by any of the stat functions

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to search the web to see how it works

Comment: [The manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) is usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to summarize :

It's impossible to get the name of the file/folder pointed by a symbolic link, using `lstat` or `stat`.

The function readlink can do the job => Man : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html. You will get example in the man

Thank you for helping me solve my problem